# MAXDOP setting algorithm for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, configuration, maxdop

When setting up a new SQL Server, I use the following code to determine a good starting point for the `MAXDOP` setting:

```
/* 
   This will recommend a MAXDOP setting appropriate for your machine's NUMA memory
   configuration.  You will need to evaluate this setting in a non-production 
   environment before moving it to production.

   MAXDOP can be configured using:  
   EXEC sp_configure 'max degree of parallelism',X;
   RECONFIGURE

   If this instance is hosting a Sharepoint database, you MUST specify MAXDOP=1 
   (URL wrapped for readability)
   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rcormier/archive/2012/10/25/
   you-shall-configure-your-maxdop-when-using-sharepoint-2013.aspx

   Biztalk (all versions, including 2010): 
   MAXDOP = 1 is only required on the BizTalk Message Box
   database server(s), and must not be changed; all other servers hosting other 
   BizTalk Server databases may return this value to 0 if set.
   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/899000
*/


DECLARE @CoreCount int;
DECLARE @NumaNodes int;

SET @CoreCount = (SELECT i.cpu_count from sys.dm_os_sys_info i);
SET @NumaNodes = (
    SELECT MAX(c.memory_node_id) + 1 
    FROM sys.dm_os_memory_clerks c 
    WHERE memory_node_id < 64
    );

IF @CoreCount > 4 /* If less than 5 cores, don't bother. */
BEGIN
    DECLARE @MaxDOP int;

    /* 3/4 of Total Cores in Machine */
    SET @MaxDOP = @CoreCount * 0.75; 

    /* if @MaxDOP is greater than the per NUMA node
       Core Count, set @MaxDOP = per NUMA node core count
    */
    IF @MaxDOP > (@CoreCount / @NumaNodes) 
        SET @MaxDOP = (@CoreCount / @NumaNodes) * 0.75;

    /*
        Reduce @MaxDOP to an even number 
    */
    SET @MaxDOP = @MaxDOP - (@MaxDOP % 2);

    /* Cap MAXDOP at 8, according to Microsoft */
    IF @MaxDOP > 8 SET @MaxDOP = 8;

    PRINT 'Suggested MAXDOP = ' + CAST(@MaxDOP as varchar(max));
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Suggested MAXDOP = 0 since you have less than 4 cores total.';
    PRINT 'This is the default setting, you likely do not need to do';
    PRINT 'anything.';
END
```

I realize this is a bit subjective, and can vary based on many things; however I'm attempting to create a tight catch-all piece of code to use as a starting point for a new server.

Does anyone have any input on this code?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The best way to do is -- use coreinfo (utility by sysinternals) as this will give you

```
a. Logical to Physical Processor Map
b. Logical Processor to Socket Map
c. Logical Processor to NUMA Node Map as below :

Logical to Physical Processor Map:
**----------------------  Physical Processor 0 (Hyperthreaded)
--**--------------------  Physical Processor 1 (Hyperthreaded)
----**------------------  Physical Processor 2 (Hyperthreaded)
------**----------------  Physical Processor 3 (Hyperthreaded)
--------**--------------  Physical Processor 4 (Hyperthreaded)
----------**------------  Physical Processor 5 (Hyperthreaded)
------------**----------  Physical Processor 6 (Hyperthreaded)
--------------**--------  Physical Processor 7 (Hyperthreaded)
----------------**------  Physical Processor 8 (Hyperthreaded)
------------------**----  Physical Processor 9 (Hyperthreaded)
--------------------**--  Physical Processor 10 (Hyperthreaded)
----------------------**  Physical Processor 11 (Hyperthreaded)
 
Logical Processor to Socket Map:
************------------  Socket 0
------------************  Socket 1
 
Logical Processor to NUMA Node Map:
************------------  NUMA Node 0
------------************  NUMA Node 1
```

Now, based on the above info, the Ideal MaxDop setting should be calculated as

```
a.  It has 12 CPU’s which are hyper threaded giving us 24 CPUs.
b.  It has 2 NUMA node [Node 0 and 1] each having 12 CPU’s with Hyperthreading ON.
c.  Number of sockets are 2 [socket 0 and 1] which are housing 12 CPU’s each.

Considering all above factors, the max degree of Parallelism should be set to 6 which is ideal value for server with above configuration.
```

So the answer is -- "**it depends**" on your processor footprint and the NUMA configuration and below table will summarize what I explained above:

```
8 or less processors    ===> 0 to N (where N= no. of processors)
More than 8 processors  ===> 8
NUMA configured         ===> MAXDOP should not exceed no of CPU’s assigned to each 
                                 NUMA node with max value capped to 8
Hyper threading Enabled ===> Should not exceed the number of physical processors.
```

***Edited:*** Below is a quick and dirty TSQL script to generate Recommendation for MAXDOP setting

```
/*************************************************************************
Author          :   Kin Shah
Purpose         :   Recommend MaxDop settings for the server instance
Tested RDBMS    :   SQL Server 2008R2

**************************************************************************/
declare @hyperthreadingRatio bit
declare @logicalCPUs int
declare @HTEnabled int
declare @physicalCPU int
declare @SOCKET int
declare @logicalCPUPerNuma int
declare @NoOfNUMA int

select @logicalCPUs = cpu_count -- [Logical CPU Count]
    ,@hyperthreadingRatio = hyperthread_ratio --  [Hyperthread Ratio]
    ,@physicalCPU = cpu_count / hyperthread_ratio -- [Physical CPU Count]
    ,@HTEnabled = case 
        when cpu_count > hyperthread_ratio
            then 1
        else 0
        end -- HTEnabled
from sys.dm_os_sys_info
option (recompile);

select @logicalCPUPerNuma = COUNT(parent_node_id) -- [NumberOfLogicalProcessorsPerNuma]
from sys.dm_os_schedulers
where [status] = 'VISIBLE ONLINE'
    and parent_node_id < 64
group by parent_node_id
option (recompile);

select @NoOfNUMA = count(distinct parent_node_id)
from sys.dm_os_schedulers -- find NO OF NUMA Nodes 
where [status] = 'VISIBLE ONLINE'
    and parent_node_id < 64

-- Report the recommendations ....
select
    --- 8 or less processors and NO HT enabled
    case 
        when @logicalCPUs < 8
            and @HTEnabled = 0
            then 'MAXDOP setting should be : ' + CAST(@logicalCPUs as varchar(3))
                --- 8 or more processors and NO HT enabled
        when @logicalCPUs >= 8
            and @HTEnabled = 0
            then 'MAXDOP setting should be : 8'
                --- 8 or more processors and HT enabled and NO NUMA
        when @logicalCPUs >= 8
            and @HTEnabled = 1
            and @NoofNUMA = 1
            then 'MaxDop setting should be : ' + CAST(@logicalCPUPerNuma / @physicalCPU as varchar(3))
                --- 8 or more processors and HT enabled and NUMA
        when @logicalCPUs >= 8
            and @HTEnabled = 1
            and @NoofNUMA > 1
            then 'MaxDop setting should be : ' + CAST(@logicalCPUPerNuma / @physicalCPU as varchar(3))
        else ''
        end as Recommendations
```

---

EDIT: For future visitors, you can look at [**test-dbamaxdop**](https://docs.dbatools.io/#Test-DbaMaxDop) powershell function (along with [other extremely helpful DBA functions](https://dbatools.io/commands/) (ALL FREE !!).

Answer (score 17):

When setting MAXDOP you typically want to limit it to the number of cores in a NUMA node. That way schedules aren't trying to access memory across numa nodes.

Answer (score 14):

Looking at a [post from the MSDN team](https://web.archive.org/web/20160305195638/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/sqlsakthi/p/maxdop-calculator-sqlserver.aspx), I've come up with a way to reliably get the physical core count from a machine, and use that to determine a good MAXDOP setting.

By "good", I mean conservative.  That is, my requirement is to use a maximum of 75% of the cores in a NUMA node, or an overall maximum of 8 cores.

SQL Server 2016 (13.x) SP2 and above, and all versions of SQL Server 2017 and above surface details about the physical core count per socket, the socket count, and the number of NUMA nodes, allowing a tidy way to determine the baseline MAXDOP setting for a new SQL Server installation.

For the versions mentioned above, this code will recommend a conservative MAXDOP setting of 75% of the number of physical cores in a NUMA node:

```
DECLARE @socket_count int;
DECLARE @cores_per_socket int;
DECLARE @numa_node_count int;
DECLARE @memory_model nvarchar(120);
DECLARE @hyperthread_ratio int;

SELECT @socket_count = dosi.socket_count
       , @cores_per_socket = dosi.cores_per_socket
       , @numa_node_count = dosi.numa_node_count
       , @memory_model = dosi.sql_memory_model_desc
       , @hyperthread_ratio = dosi.hyperthread_ratio
FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info dosi;

SELECT [Socket Count] = @socket_count
       , [Cores Per Socket] = @cores_per_socket
       , [Number of NUMA nodes] = @numa_node_count
       , [Hyperthreading Enabled] = CASE WHEN @hyperthread_ratio > @cores_per_socket THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       , [Lock Pages in Memory granted?] = CASE WHEN @memory_model = N'CONVENTIONAL' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END;

DECLARE @MAXDOP int = @cores_per_socket;
SET @MAXDOP = @MAXDOP * 0.75;
IF @MAXDOP >= 8 SET @MAXDOP = 8;

SELECT [Recommended MAXDOP setting] = @MAXDOP
       , [Command] = 'EXEC sys.sp_configure N''max degree of parallelism'', ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @MAXDOP) + ';RECONFIGURE;';
```

For versions of SQL Server prior to SQL Server 2017 or SQL Server 2016 SP2, you cannot obtain the core-count-per-numa-node from `sys.dm_os_sys_info`.  Instead, we can use PowerShell to determine the physical core count:

```
powershell -OutputFormat Text -NoLogo -Command "& {Get-WmiObject -namespace 
"root\CIMV2" -class Win32_Processor -Property NumberOfCores} | select NumberOfCores"
```

One can also use PowerShell to determine the number of logical cores, which would likely be double the number of physical cores if HyperThreading is turned on:

```
powershell -OutputFormat Text -NoLogo -Command "& {Get-WmiObject -namespace 
"root\CIMV2" -class Win32_Processor -Property NumberOfCores} 
| select NumberOfLogicalProcessors"
```

The T-SQL:

```
/* 
   This will recommend a MAXDOP setting appropriate for your machine's NUMA memory
   configuration.  You will need to evaluate this setting in a non-production 
   environment before moving it to production.

   MAXDOP can be configured using:  
   EXEC sp_configure 'max degree of parallelism',X;
   RECONFIGURE

   If this instance is hosting a Sharepoint database, you MUST specify MAXDOP=1 
   (URL wrapped for readability)
   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rcormier/archive/2012/10/25/
   you-shall-configure-your-maxdop-when-using-sharepoint-2013.aspx

   Biztalk (all versions, including 2010): 
   MAXDOP = 1 is only required on the BizTalk Message Box
   database server(s), and must not be changed; all other servers hosting other 
   BizTalk Server databases may return this value to 0 if set.
   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/899000
*/
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @CoreCount int;
SET @CoreCount = 0;
DECLARE @NumaNodes int;

/*  see if xp_cmdshell is enabled, so we can try to use 
    PowerShell to determine the real core count
*/
DECLARE @T TABLE (
    name varchar(255)
    , minimum int
    , maximum int
    , config_value int
    , run_value int
);
INSERT INTO @T 
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell';
DECLARE @cmdshellEnabled BIT;
SET @cmdshellEnabled = 0;
SELECT @cmdshellEnabled = 1 
FROM @T
WHERE run_value = 1;
IF @cmdshellEnabled = 1
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #cmdshell
    (
        txt VARCHAR(255)
    );
    INSERT INTO #cmdshell (txt)
    EXEC xp_cmdshell 'powershell -OutputFormat Text -NoLogo -Command "& {Get-WmiObject -namespace "root\CIMV2" -class Win32_Processor -Property NumberOfCores} | select NumberOfCores"';
    SELECT @CoreCount = CONVERT(INT, LTRIM(RTRIM(txt)))
    FROM #cmdshell
    WHERE ISNUMERIC(LTRIM(RTRIM(txt)))=1;
    DROP TABLE #cmdshell;
END
IF @CoreCount = 0 
BEGIN
    /* 
        Could not use PowerShell to get the corecount, use SQL Server's 
        unreliable number.  For machines with hyperthreading enabled
        this number is (typically) twice the physical core count.
    */
    SET @CoreCount = (SELECT i.cpu_count from sys.dm_os_sys_info i); 
END

SET @NumaNodes = (
    SELECT MAX(c.memory_node_id) + 1 
    FROM sys.dm_os_memory_clerks c 
    WHERE memory_node_id < 64
    );

DECLARE @MaxDOP int;

/* 3/4 of Total Cores in Machine */
SET @MaxDOP = @CoreCount * 0.75; 

/* if @MaxDOP is greater than the per NUMA node
    Core Count, set @MaxDOP = per NUMA node core count
*/
IF @MaxDOP > (@CoreCount / @NumaNodes) 
    SET @MaxDOP = (@CoreCount / @NumaNodes) * 0.75;

/*
    Reduce @MaxDOP to an even number 
*/
SET @MaxDOP = @MaxDOP - (@MaxDOP % 2);

/* Cap MAXDOP at 8, according to Microsoft */
IF @MaxDOP > 8 SET @MaxDOP = 8;

PRINT 'Suggested MAXDOP = ' + CAST(@MaxDOP as varchar(max));
```

Answer (score 11):

As a general rule, use higher DOP for an OLAP system, and lower (or no) DOP for an OLTP system. Many systems are somewhere in between, so find a happy medium that allows the occasional large workload to get enough CPU to complete quickly, without strangling your OLTP workloads.

Also, be careful about using the `cpu_count` column to get a core count. If hyperthreading is enabled, this column seems to reflect the number of logical processors exposed. Generally speaking, you don't want DOP to be higher than the number of physical cores. Spreading a heavy parallel workload across logical processors will just increase overhead with no real benefit.

There's also a `hyperthread_ratio` column, but I'm not certain what it represents. The documentation isn't very clear either. The number I see on our system suggests it could either be the number of physical cores in the entire system, or the number of logical processors per chip. The documentation claims I should be seeing a different figure entirely.

Comment: I believe the `hyperthread_ratio` is the amount of logical cores per processor.  I ran into that a little while back and if I'm remember correctly that is the conclusion I came to.  Maybe @AaronBertrand has more info on that.  Don't take that as a hard and fast fact yet before verification.

Comment: @ThomasStringer the documentation states that, and from running it on multiple machines, that is what it looks like.  However, it is pretty difficult to tell from that column whether hyperthreading is actually enabled or not.  For instance, on one of my servers it reports 8 - the server has 2 physical CPUs, with 4 cores on each CPU, with hyperthreading enabled.  On machines without hyperthreading it reports 4 under the same circumstances, but without rebooting (and turning hyperthreading off), you'd never see that change!

Answer (score 8):

I also have stumbled about the article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2806535 and cannot find the correlation to the scripts above.

Also I'm wondering, why there exists a differentiation for "@logicalCPUs >= 8 and @HTEnabled = 1 and @NoofNUMA = 1" and "@logicalCPUs >= 8 and @HTEnabled = 1 and @NoofNUMA > 1" as the result becomes the same.

After all I ended up writing my own piece of code matching the article from above, though even there I would have loved a more precise definition and/or differentiation about "processors" "CPU" and "physical processors".

Feel free to have your spin with it.

```
/*************************************************************************
Author          :   Dennis Winter (Thought: Adapted from a script from "Kin Shah")
Purpose         :   Recommend MaxDop settings for the server instance
Tested RDBMS    :   SQL Server 2008R2

**************************************************************************/
declare @hyperthreadingRatio bit
declare @logicalCPUs int
declare @HTEnabled int
declare @physicalCPU int
declare @SOCKET int
declare @logicalCPUPerNuma int
declare @NoOfNUMA int
declare @MaxDOP int

select @logicalCPUs = cpu_count -- [Logical CPU Count]
    ,@hyperthreadingRatio = hyperthread_ratio --  [Hyperthread Ratio]
    ,@physicalCPU = cpu_count / hyperthread_ratio -- [Physical CPU Count]
    ,@HTEnabled = case 
        when cpu_count > hyperthread_ratio
            then 1
        else 0
        end -- HTEnabled
from sys.dm_os_sys_info
option (recompile);

select @logicalCPUPerNuma = COUNT(parent_node_id) -- [NumberOfLogicalProcessorsPerNuma]
from sys.dm_os_schedulers
where [status] = 'VISIBLE ONLINE'
    and parent_node_id < 64
group by parent_node_id
option (recompile);

select @NoOfNUMA = count(distinct parent_node_id)
from sys.dm_os_schedulers -- find NO OF NUMA Nodes 
where [status] = 'VISIBLE ONLINE'
    and parent_node_id < 64

IF @NoofNUMA > 1 AND @HTEnabled = 0
    SET @MaxDOP= @logicalCPUPerNuma 
ELSE IF  @NoofNUMA > 1 AND @HTEnabled = 1
    SET @MaxDOP=round( @NoofNUMA  / @physicalCPU *1.0,0)
ELSE IF @HTEnabled = 0
    SET @MaxDOP=@logicalCPUs
ELSE IF @HTEnabled = 1
    SET @MaxDOP=@physicalCPU

IF @MaxDOP > 10
    SET @MaxDOP=10
IF @MaxDOP = 0
    SET @MaxDOP=1

PRINT 'logicalCPUs : '         + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @logicalCPUs)
PRINT 'hyperthreadingRatio : ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @hyperthreadingRatio) 
PRINT 'physicalCPU : '         + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @physicalCPU) 
PRINT 'HTEnabled : '           + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @HTEnabled)
PRINT 'logicalCPUPerNuma : '   + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @logicalCPUPerNuma) 
PRINT 'NoOfNUMA : '            + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @NoOfNUMA)
PRINT '---------------------------'
Print 'MAXDOP setting should be : ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @MaxDOP)
```

Comment: Nice piece of code.  I'm not sure if you realize the `hyperthread_ratio` column in `sys.dm_os_sys_info` is misleading...  on my workstation, for example, I have a single 4-core CPU with hyperthreading enabled - Task Manager sees 8 logical CPUs, and your code reports the hyperthreading ratio to be 1.

Comment: As an FYI, my code produces a recommendation of 6 for this machine, which will leave 2 cores available even under the most stressful parallel queries.

Comment: The hyperthread_ratio is indeed an issue, though cannot be solved better - at least not to my knowledge.
See this Blog for some further details: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/kalen_delaney/archive/2007/12/08/hyperthreaded-or-not.aspx

And about your second post - I would be nice to know, which value for "max degree of parallism" you have chosen for your machine. :-D
Also I'm quite new in this topic - just stumbled over this just because I didn't knew before and needed this information. Thus what would be your conclusion, is the 2 cores still available a good thing or bad?

Answer (score 4):

This version gives you a nice single result set with the existing MAXDOP setting and should hold up on versions SQL 2008-2017 without the need to use xp_cmdshell.

```
select
[ServerName]                    = @@SERVERNAME
, [ComputerName]                = SERVERPROPERTY('ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS') 
, [LogicalCPUs]             
, hyperthread_ratio 
, [PhysicalCPU]             
, [HTEnabled]               
, LogicalCPUPerNuma
, [NoOfNUMA]
, [MaxDop_Recommended]          = convert(int,case when [MaxDop_RAW] > 10 then 10 else [MaxDop_RAW] end)
, [MaxDop_Current]              = sc.value
, [MaxDop_RAW]
, [Number of Cores] 
from
(
select
     [LogicalCPUs]              
    , hyperthread_ratio 
    , [PhysicalCPU]             
    , [HTEnabled]               
    , LogicalCPUPerNuma
    , [NoOfNUMA]
    , [Number of Cores] 
    , [MaxDop_RAW]              = 
        case
            when [NoOfNUMA] > 1 AND HTEnabled = 0 then logicalCPUPerNuma 
            when [NoOfNUMA] > 1 AND HTEnabled = 1 then convert(decimal(9,4),[NoOfNUMA]/ convert(decimal(9,4),Res_MAXDOP.PhysicalCPU) * convert(decimal(9,4),1))
            when HTEnabled = 0 then  Res_MAXDOP.LogicalCPUs
            when HTEnabled = 1 then  Res_MAXDOP.PhysicalCPU
        end
from
(
    select
         [LogicalCPUs]              = osi.cpu_count
        , osi.hyperthread_ratio 
        , [PhysicalCPU]             = osi.cpu_count/osi.hyperthread_ratio
        , [HTEnabled]               = case when osi.cpu_count > osi.hyperthread_ratio then 1 else 0 end
        , LogicalCPUPerNuma
        , [NoOfNUMA]
        , [Number of Cores] 
    from 
    (
        select
            [NoOfNUMA]  = count(res.parent_node_id)
            ,[Number of Cores]  = res.LogicalCPUPerNuma/count(res.parent_node_id)
            ,res.LogicalCPUPerNuma
        from
        (
            Select
                s.parent_node_id
                ,LogicalCPUPerNuma  = count(1)
            from
                sys.dm_os_schedulers s
            where
                s.parent_node_id < 64
                and
                s.status = 'VISIBLE ONLINE'
            group by 
                s.parent_node_id
        ) Res
        group by
            res.LogicalCPUPerNuma
    ) Res_NUMA
    cross apply sys.dm_os_sys_info osi
) Res_MAXDOP
)Res_Final
cross apply sys.sysconfigures sc
where sc.comment = 'maximum degree of parallelism'
option (recompile);
```

Answer (score 3):

Nice script, but the kb article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2806535 doesn't completely jive with your code.  What am I missing?

Server 1
HTEnabled: 1
hyperthreadingRatio: 12
logical cpus: 24
physical cpus: 2
logical cpus per numa: 12
NoOfNuma: 2
MaxDop setting should be : 6

Server 2
HTEnabled: 2
hyperthreadingRatio: 16
logical cpus: 64
physical cpus: 4
logical cpus per numa: 16
NoOfNuma: 4
MaxDop setting should be : 4

I realize these are just suggestions; but something doesn't seem right to me that a server (#2) above with 4 processors instead of 2, and 8 cores per physical CPU instead of 6; would recommend the MAXDOP at 4, versus 6 for the less powerful server.

The kbb article above suggests 8 my scenario above. "For servers that have NUMA configured and hyperthreading enabled, the MAXDOP value should not exceed number of physical processors per NUMA node."

Comment: If you set MAXDOP higher than the number of cores/numa node, you end up with calls into far memory which are many many times slower than calling near memory.  This is because each numa node has its own memory; having a query use more threads than are present in a single numa mode will spread the CPU load over multiple cores, and therefore multiple memory nodes.

Comment: I recommend setting MAXDOP to a setting that makes sense for your server running your load.  Only you can determine the best setting for your particular load; this post is only a guideline.

Answer (score 3):

During installation of SQL Server 2019 CTP 3.0 there is a new tab MaxDOP. The actual value is predefined(in previous versions the default was 0).

[Setting MAXDOP During SQL Server 2019 Setup](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/setting-maxdop-during-sql-server-2019-setup/)

[image]

<sub>Image source: https://www.brentozar.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/SQL_Server_2019_Setup.png</sub>