# SQL Server 2008: DoMiniDump () encountered error (0x80004005) - Unspecified error

Tags: sql-server-2008

We're running a SQL Server 2008 database and are getting the following output(error?) in our logs:

```
06/23/2015 21:56:41,Server,Unknown,Process 214:0:42 (0x73b0) Worker 0x0000000BB2CC61A0 appears to be non-yielding on Scheduler 39. Thread creation time: 13079558329722. Approx Thread CPU Used: kernel 0 ms<c/> user 0 ms. Process Utilization 8%. System Idle 91%. Interval: 70169 ms.
06/23/2015 21:56:41,Server,Unknown,DoMiniDump () encountered error (0x80004005) - Unspecified error
06/23/2015 21:56:41,Server,Unknown,External dump process return code 0x20000001.<nl/>External dump process returned no errors.
06/23/2015 21:56:38,Server,Unknown,Stack Signature for the dump is 0x000000000000028A
06/23/2015 21:56:38,Server,Unknown,* *******************************************************************************
06/23/2015 21:56:38,Server,Unknown,*
06/23/2015 21:56:38,Server,Unknown,* Non-yielding Scheduler
06/23/2015 21:56:38,Server,Unknown,*
06/23/2015 21:56:38,Server,Unknown,*   06/23/15 21:56:38 spid 8656
06/23/2015 21:56:38,Server,Unknown,* BEGIN STACK DUMP:
06/23/2015 21:56:38,Server,Unknown,*
06/23/2015 21:56:38,Server,Unknown,* *******************************************************************************
06/23/2015 21:56:38,Server,Unknown,***Unable to get thread context for spid 0
06/23/2015 21:56:38,Server,Unknown,Using 'dbghelp.dll' version '4.0.5'
```

I can't find much about this on google. There a lot of similar errors, which talk about hanging sql servers and that this might be a user trying to execute a dump that has no permission? I can't find anything about this exact error though.

Could anybody point me in the right direction or know immediately what is causing this?

Note: We've been getting the following error as well, which might have something do with it, but I'm not sure:

```
06/23/2015 22:22:50,spid23s,Unknown,SQL Server failed to prepare DTC transaction. Failure code: 8522.
06/23/2015 22:22:50,spid23s,Unknown,Error: 8565<c/> Severity: 16<c/> State: 1.
06/23/2015 22:22:50,spid23s,Unknown,Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MS DTC) has stopped this transaction.
06/23/2015 22:22:50,spid23s,Unknown,Error: 8522<c/> Severity: 16<c/> State: 1.
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Error 80004005 is a generic error message. Can you please post the exact build number of your SQL Server. If you can upload the minidump files that would also help

Comment: You wont find much information about how to analyse stack dump. Stack dump due to non Yeilding schedulers are mostly created due to bug in SQL Server. What is output of Select @@Version

Comment: Hi, thank you both. Version/build is: 

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP3) - 10.0.5500.0 (X64) 
 Sep 21 2011 22:45:45 
 Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation
 Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

I'll try and find the minidump files.

Comment: That is not the most up-to-date build. You could try installing SP4

Comment: You should [download SP4](http://sqlserverupdates.com/sql-server-2008-updates/) as suggested by @MartinSmith. You are facing a classic - [**worker thread starvation issue.**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/47242/8783). I bet that your MAXDOP is set to default (0) - which I recommend [setting to a more sensible value](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/36578/8783).