# Large Sleep counts causing THREADPOOL wait?

Tags: sql-server, performance, wait-types

When I run `sp_whoisactive` throughout the day, I usually see we have around 500-700 connections on our server. We are occasionally getting THREADPOOL waits and high signal wait ratios (so we are thread starved at times).

However, these 500-700 connections only 10-25 of them are active. I wasn't sure if a sleeping `SPID` is still bound to a thread while it sleeps?

Could that be causing our high signal wait ratio and THREADPOOL waits?

I have a feeling our 3rd party application is not properly closing out connections and is causing us issues, but wanted to check first before I bring this up with them. Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/115518/8783). Make sure you have max dop set away from default value.

Comment: Yes it already is. What I really want to know is do sleeping sessions hold a thread?

Answer (score 1):

> What I really want to know is do sleeping sessions hold a thread?

No, they do not,

> A SQL Server worker thread, also known as worker or thread, is a
>   logical representation of an operating system thread. When executing
>   serial requests, **the SQL Server Database Engine will spawn a worker to
>   execute the active task**.

But instead of actually spawning a new worker, one is typicall available in a pool

> The max worker threads option enables SQL Server to create a pool of
>   worker threads to service a larger number of query requests, which
>   improves performance.

[Thread and Task Architecture Guide -- SQL Server task scheduling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/thread-and-task-architecture-guide?view=sql-server-ver15#sql-server-task-scheduling)

which you can see from running

```
select count(*)
from sys.dm_os_workers

select count(*)
from sys.dm_exec_sessions
```

Since you typically have more sessions than workers.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose they could be bound to a thread while they are inactive, but they shouldn't be causing threadpool waits if they are just sitting there. I'd look at what those active sessions are doing. See if they have a "CXPACKET" wait type, that could show that those active sessions are using multiple threads to perform their actions. Here is a good article about CXPACKET with some troubleshooting tips: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2027/a-closer-look-at-cxpacket-wait-type-in-sql-server/