# How can I monitor my server’s status before changing the “Cost threshold for parallelism” settings

Tags: sql-server, performance, parallelism, performance-tuning

Our production server is running SQL Server 2008 SP3.

I’ve read a post on “cost threshold for parallelism” - http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/tuning-cost-threshold-for-parallelism-from-the-plan-cache/
And I have a few questions.

We have a relatively high amount of CXPACKET wait events on our production server (in average of 85%).
The server has default values for “cost threshold for parallelism” and “Max Degree of Parallelism”

I started to explore the possibility of increasing the value of “cost threshold for parallelism”.
I suspect the indeed the value is too low, but I wanted to get as much information as possible before I change anything and not just change it to 25 or 50 because that’s what the some of the internet posts suggested.

I’ve read this nice post about how to determine the value:
http://sqlknowitall.com/determining-a-setting-for-cost-threshold-for-parallelism/

The median cost in my server was 63.

How can I monitor my server’s status “before” and “after” I change to settings, in order to verify the effect of the value on the system’s throughput?

Thanks in advance,
Roni.

Comment: I would look at your wait stats before the change and then after. Do your CXPACKET waits go down? Also important to look at the procedure stats to see how many went up in execution time versus decreased.

Comment: What is the MAXDOP setting on the sql server instance ?

Comment: Well, your CXPACKET wait type will be a decent indicator, for starters.  We changed ours and our CXPACKET waits went from ~60% to about 20%.  I monitored overall CPU usage and took 10 queries (5 that would run parallel, 5 that wouldn't with the new change) and checked their processing times before and after. Changing this setting is letting your processors work more efficiently so big queries get the horsepower and don't have to fight with smaller queries that may be going parallel unnecessarily.

Comment: Also, make sure you understand that changing these settings will blow away your procedure cache so performance may get poky afterwards until your plan cache is rebuilt.  Don't do this during production hours.

Comment: @Roni - have you determined that leaving the MAXDOP setting at the default is a good idea?  I'd estimate that is one of the primary causes the symptoms you're seeing.  Have you looked at http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36522/what-is-a-good-repeatable-way-to-calculate-maxdop-on-sql-server ?

Comment: @Roni - whatever you do, there should be a **baseline** for your server that you can compare with - either good or bad when you change key things like MAXDOP, COST THRESHOLD, etc. This way you can guage if the change was good or made things worse.

Comment: I'm going to take a contrarian perspective and say that you should eliminate other possible offenders first. What is causing CXPACKET waits? You can change MAXDOP and CTP top decrease the waits for that type, but you may not be addressing the underlying issue. Are you getting other cpu-associated waits that would indicate thread starvation? Are you getting deadlocked scheduler errors and minidumps? Are your queries going parallel and each thread is waiting for storage? Latches? You can't evaluate CXPACKET in isolation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for all the helpers.
I've created a base line from the below link, to check my instance before and after the parameter change:
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/baselines/96797/

Answer (score -1):

If you have a lot of CXPACKET waits it is possible that <strike>reducing</strike> setting the MaxDOP is appropriate and will help. You should not change the cost threshold for parallelism setting assuming you have a NUMA machine (which you most likely do).

MaxDOP: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2806535

...and I read somewhere that cost threshold needn't be changed but am still trying to track that link down :(

In any case, focus on MaxDOP.

Comment: Did you read the question OP said she has default value for max degree of parallelism and you are asking to decrease it changing max dop after seeing CXPACKET wait is knee jerk reaction. You need to see other waits which are just after CXPACKET

Comment: If he has the default, is it right?