# why sql server has high Worker threads?

Tags: sql-server, maxdop

Product : SQL Server 2008 (SP4)

CPU : 64

64-Bit system

Worker thread configuration = 0

SCOM Alerts : SQL DB 2008 Engine Thread Count is too high

---

After receiving this alert from SCOM i have queried [sys.dm_os_sys_info] and
[sys.dm_os_threads] to check the Total number of threads \ used \ available and found them as follow :

Total    ---     Used   ---     Free    ---    Used Percentage

1472     ---    1260    ---    212      -----      85 %

this server is used for online transactions processing. Is it normal that the Used threads are always between 1100 and 1300 throughout the day ? which obviously cause this alert to be sent when too many queries are executing on the server ?

Moreover, Is this related to the configuration of MAX Degree of Parallelism (Which is set to 0) that causes queries exceed threshold use parallel threads to finish ?

Thanks

Comment: How many simultaneous clients do you expect to have?

Comment: Does your server have 64 cores?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set MAXDOP and "Cost Threshold for Parallelism" according to best practices.

MAXDOP should generally be set to the number of cores per NUMA node.  See my question [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36522/what-is-a-good-repeatable-way-to-calculate-maxdop-on-sql-server) for more details.

Cost Threshold for Parallelism should likely be set to at least 50.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Does this mean that when MAXDOP = 0 and cost threshold for paraellelism = 5 queries will use multiple threads and that why i see worker threads between 1000 - 1200 all the time ?

Comment: That might be causing the symptoms.  How many simultaneous clients/queries are running on your server?  A lot?

Comment: well, it depends on the time of the day as this instance is mainly for online transactions. are you asking about a specific value on a DMV ?

Comment: no, I'm wondering if you have a massive system or website attached and are thinking you might have thousands of customers using your SQL Server services.  For instance, if you are only a small shop with 15 employees, then seeing 1000 threads in use would *probably* be cause for alarm.  If, however, you are servicing a million queries an hour, maybe it's not such a big deal.

Comment: Nope its not attached to a website at all. All is payments transactions. anyway i have checked the wait_info and found CXPACKET OVER 55% which makes me going forward re configuring the MAXDOP and Cost Threshold.

Comment: Thanks Max, Reconfiguring MAXDOP and Cost Threshold solved this issue and thread count is normaly now

Comment: I'm glad I could help.