# SQL Server performance issue (CXPACKET wait type)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, performance, optimization, wait-types

I have a performance issue with production SQL Server 2012 which has 24 cores and 32 GB of RAM. From wait type I can see CXPACKET is on the top based on the following SQL Server metrics, should I reduce MAXDOP or "cost Threshold for Parallelism" to avoid more parallelism and reduce CXPACKET wait type?

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: CXPACKET waits are not actually a harmful waits they are more of indicators and normally wait just below this wait is what causing the issue. Now what is MAXDOP you have set as of now. Also run Query mentioned in [This SE Thread](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36522/what-is-a-good-repeatable-way-to-calculate-maxdop-on-sql-server) to get correct value that you should use for MAXDOP and tell it to me.

Comment: reducing cost threshold for parallelism will make it worse, not better. Have you changed from the default Cost Threshold 5 and MAXDOP 0? They're probably not good defaults for your server.

Comment: Please read this : http://www.scarydba.com/2017/02/20/estimated-costs-queries/ 
maybe this will help you in setting a more properly `Cost Threshold for ||`
and there is one more http://www.scarydba.com/2017/02/28/determining-the-cost-threshold-for-parallelism/ (for 2016)

Comment: Thanks, Shanky. the current value is 0 which means unlimited, and the recommended query returned 5 as MaxDop value, so should I update the maxdop to 5? I'm wondering if the number of full scan/s is usual or not.

Comment: What do you think about cost Threshold for Parallelism setting? any recommendation?

Comment: I would start with 5 and see whether we still see chunk of CXPACKET waits, remember I also told sometimes such wait is normal. Also I would change `cost threshold for parallelism` to 40 or 30. This is tentative value but I believe you would see some respite.

Answer (score -1):

General consensus seems to tend torwards setting Cost Threshold for Parallelism to 50 and go from there.
[Why Cost Threshold For Parallelism Shouldn’t Be Set To 5](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/03/why-cost-threshold-for-parallelism-shouldnt-be-set-to-5/)

This even includes official reccomendations from VMWare regarding SQL Server Setup with vSphere. Section 4.5 of the Guide "Architecting Microsoft SQL Server on VMware vSphere®" states:

> The default value is 5 which is usually considered too low. [...] The recommendation instead is to increase the CTFP value from 5 seconds to approximately 50 seconds to make sure only large queries run in parallel. Set the MAXDOP according to Microsoft’s recommendation for the number of cores in the VM’s NUMA node (no more than 8).

The usage of of the unit "seconds" should be taken with a grain of salt because on modern systems and versions of SQL Server it will not reflect the actual duration in seconds.

Regarding MAXDOP there is a comprehensive guide found here: [Configure the max degree of parallelism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-max-degree-of-parallelism-server-configuration-option)

So in your case I would start with the following settings and test them out:

*Cost Threshold for Parallelism: 50*

*Maximum Degree of Parallelism: 8*

Comment: @KrisGruttemeyer -- what you edited out was a quote; you probably should revert your edit and add a comment. [Source](https://www.vmware.com/content/dam/digitalmarketing/vmware/en/pdf/solutions/sql-server-on-vmware-best-practices-guide.pdf), page 48.

Comment: I understand it's a quote, but it's also not technically correct.  Query cost units are not seconds, it's unitless.

Comment: You cannot arbitrarily change a _quote_ -- because it's a quote. Besides, the [horse's mouth](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188603(v=sql.105).aspx) says this: "_The cost refers to an estimated elapsed time in seconds required to run the serial plan on a specific hardware configuration._" How'bout that?

Comment: I'll revert my change but also, per Brent Ozar: "They’re still a valuable reference metric, but they are, even for actual plans, still an estimated cost. Pay attention to them. Pay attention to the fact that THEY DON’T MEAN SECONDS ANYMORE."  https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/03/why-cost-threshold-for-parallelism-shouldnt-be-set-to-5/

Comment: @KrisGruttemeyer -- Thank you for trying to clarify my post. I do agree with your intention. But since this is a direct quote I will revert it.

Comment: Also, to further the 'seconds' aren't right anymore, I checked a server of mine that has a query that averages 5 seconds.  It's subtree cost is 43.  So, there's that.  I understand that the MS documentation also says seconds, but that that was written back when SQL Server 7 was around.  Things have changed quite a bit and many MVPs/MCMs have written about it not being right.