# MAX NUMA/ "Affinity" in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, numa

Is there now, or possibly in the works a way to tell SQL Server to stay inside one NUMA node, either server wide or at the query level?   Basically the same functionality as MAXDOP, but MAXNUMA?

Right now, unless I am totally missing it, when a query goes parallel it can use all of the processors it can see.   Just wondering if there is a way to restrict it to one or two or 'x' NUMA nodes.  I may not really want my queries spread out over 80 logical processors :)

This is mostly a curiosity rather than a "help me break my broken thing" question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...a way to tell SQL Server to stay inside one NUMA node...

There's no hint that does that, but SQL Server can be configured to do what you describe. See [SQL Server Parallel Query Placement Decision Logic](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2016/03/04/sql-server-parallel-query-placement-decision-logic/) by the Microsoft SQL Server Customer Service and Support Team for details. The table below is reproduced from that post:

> [image: Thread placement logic]

Also, from [NUMA Connection Affinity and Parallel Queries](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2007/06/28/numa-connection-affinity-and-parallel-queries/) on the same blog:

> - If the DOP for the query can be satisfied by a single node the ideal node (most workers, schedulers and memory available at the time the query is started) is selected.  The controlling worker can be on a different node than the ideal.  For example you could have NUMA port affinity established for NODE 1 but the parallel query executes on NODE 4 because 4 was the ideal node.   This is not a problem because the majority of the work is done by the parallel workers which are located together on a node.

Answer (score 2):

You could use SQL Server's "processor affinity" to limit processing to a single NUMA node.  See the `<process affinity>` section of the `ALTER SERVER CONFIGURATION` command on [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210585.aspx) for more details.

By default, SQL Server attempts to keep query processing contained inside a given NUMA node if the query goes parallel where MAXDOP <= number of cores per NUMA node.  The indication here is to configure MAXDOP to a reasonable value; certainly not more than the number of cores per NUMA node.  There are a load of resources to help with calculating a reasonable MAXDOP; including the answers on [my question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36522/what-is-a-good-repeatable-way-to-calculate-maxdop-on-sql-server).