# What is the MAXDOP value for the server which doesn't have NUMA

Tags: sql-server, configuration, maxdop

Im using a SQL Server with the below configurations.

- 4 Core.
- 8 Logical processors.
- No NUMA.
- NO hyperthreading.

I read this Doc:

[Recommendations and guidelines for the "max degree of parallelism" configuration option in SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2806535/recommendations-and-guidelines-for-the-max-degree-of-parallelism-confi)

Since I don't have NUMA and HyperThread.

So what could be my best MAXDOP setting?

Comment: I saw this post already, even the microsoft link which I added in the question is telling the answer for that. But my question is `I don't have NUMA support` so what could be the best value?

Comment: What was output when you run queries mentioned in the link ?

Comment: I got the value 4

Comment: Then start with 4 even I would have started with 4 because there are 4 cores. Also note that the value is not absolute but almost correct.

Comment: You could try the PowerShell module dbatools. There is a command to test your MaxDop settings for the whole instance or per database
`Import-Module dbatools`
`Test-DbaMaxDop -SqlInstance localhost\SQL2017`

Comment: The DBAtools returns 8, So I have no NUMA but I have 1 socket. (My windows server is in AWS - Virtualized). So how SQL consider this as a NUMA ?

Comment: You can't have 4 cores and 8 logical threads without hyperthreading, fyi. You either have a full core (execution unit) or you don't. 8 execution units would be 8 full cores.

Comment: Im running this on AWS (virtualization)

Comment: Post the output of COREINFO.exe as I described in (https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/36578/8783)

Answer (score -1):

For SQL Server 2005 and later versions

Server with single NUMA node    Less than 8 logical processors  Keep MAXDOP at or below # of logical processors

Server with single NUMA node    Greater than 8 logical processors   Keep MAXDOP at 8

Server with multiple NUMA nodes Less than 8 logical processors per NUMA node Keep MAXDOP at or below # of logical processors per NUMA node

Server with multiple NUMA nodes Greater than 8 logical processors per NUMA node Keep MAXDOP at 8

See : [Recommendations and guidelines for the "max degree of parallelism" configuration option in SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2806535/recommendations-and-guidelines-for-the-max-degree-of-parallelism-confi)