# What is the num of NUMA nodes for MAXDOP calculation when there is discrepancy between various ways to count the NUMA nodes?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, maxdop, numa

Querying the dm_os_performance_counters shows that I have **2** NUMA nodes:

```
select *
from sys.dm_os_performance_counters
where object_name = 'SQLServer:Buffer Node'
and counter_name = 'Page life expectancy'
```

Querying the **sys.dm_os_sys_info** shows:

```
Numa node count 4
CPU count 24
Softnumae_configuration 1
Socket_count 24
Cores per socket 1
```

[image]

Where as when I right click on **SQL server properties**, click on Processors it shows 2 NUMA nodes, each with 12 CPUs.

[image]

[image]

**SQL error log**:

```
SQL Server detected 24 sockets with 1 cores per socket and 1 logical processors 
per socket. 24 total logical processors.

Automatic soft-NUMA was enabled because SQL server has detected hardware NUMA nodes 
with greater than 8 physical cores.
```

[image]

[image]

So what is the final value of NUMA and CPUs?

I am asking because it is recommended to have the MAX DOP configured based on the number of NUMA nodes and the processors per node (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-max-degree-of-parallelism-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver15#Recommendations). How to decide on the **MAX DOP** when there  is discrepancy between processor count reported in **sys.dm_os_sys_info** vs **server properties** vs **SQL error logs**?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MAXDOP setting algorithm for SQL Server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36522/maxdop-setting-algorithm-for-sql-server)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re seeing soft-NUMA counts.

As mentioned in this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-max-degree-of-parallelism-server-configuration-option)…

> Starting with SQL Server 2016 (13.x), during service startup if the Database Engine detects more than eight physical cores per NUMA node or socket at startup, soft-NUMA nodes are created automatically by default. The Database Engine places logical processors from the same physical core into different soft-NUMA nodes. The recommendations in the table below are aimed at keeping all the worker threads of a parallel query within the same soft-NUMA node.

In your case, it looks like you have 2 CPUs, each with 12 cores. With those being greater than 8, SQL Server is breaking them up into 4 soft-NUMA nodes at startup, each with 6 cores. With this configuration, you’d want to set MAXDOP to 6.